# Can we prove that axioms do not contradict?

Tags: logic, axioms, incompleteness

We construct many structures by chosing a set of axioms and deriving everything else from them. As far as I remember we never proved in our lectures that those axioms do not contradict. So:

Is it always possible to prove that a set of axioms does not contain a contradiction? (So if not could we perhaps find a contradiction in a structure that we definde by axioms someday?) Or is it proven that doing so is impossible?

Comment: I don't claim to know all about this topic (in fact, I know pretty much nothing about it), but this makes me think of Godel's Incompleteness Theorem.

Comment: I'm not an expert in logic but I believe that consistency of a theory cannot be proved in the theory itself; however, you can prove it in another theory in which you construct a model of your theory (such as Peano arithmetic in ZFC). But then you need to assume that the other theory is consistent.

Comment: @Clarinetist That's because this is exactly what Godel's Incompleteness Theorem is about.

Answer (score 9):

Proved from what?

Even logic is formalized in a mathematical fashion, so it has a mathematical backbone. We need to first **assume** that first-order logic does not include a contradiction. Then we need to decide on which system we are going to use to develop our mathematics. Arithmetical systems will suffice for syntactical manipulations of strings, and set theoretical systems will suffice for semantical proofs using models.

Whatever meta-theory, in which we formalized the logic and the proofs and whatnot, you are working in, if it is sufficiently strong, it will not prove its own consistency. This means that along with the assumption that first-order logic does not contain a contradiction, we implicitly assume that our meta-theory is consistent, whatever it might be. And the more we need, the more consistency we will have to prove.

Goedel proved that a theory which is both consistent, recursively enumerable, and interprets arithmetics, cannot prove its own consistency (and is therefore not complete). This means that we really have to assume the consistency of our meta-theory (which is usually a theory satisfying these conditions).

Of course, we can prove the consistency of arithmetic, using set theory, and the consistency of set theory using an even stronger set theory, and so on. But that's not what you're looking for in an answer. The answer, simply, is that at some point, you have to take some things for granted. The question is how much you are willing to take for granted, how much logic and foundational theories you are familiar with, to transform an argument form one system to another.

Comment: Asaf, as far as I understand the "intention" behind the OP, the question is really trying to ask why is first order logic with its usual logical axioms consistent (let's work with the empty language). Frankly, I cannot think of a way to explain it except "if they were inconsistent, the universe would explode". Because once you try to formalize this question within an axiomatic system, as you have noted, we have to assume the consistency of whatever we are working in anyway.

Comment: Burak, I agree, that it isn't likely that FOL is inconsistent. But that's the sort of thing which amounts to belief. Either as some sort of a Platonist, which thinks that mathematical objects exist in some ideal universe; or as a formalist which just pushes strings on paper. Or, like me, as an agnostic person who just enjoys the game regardless to its nature. Either case, this is a matter of belief, rather than a mathematical issue.

Comment: Agreed. I think the problem here is that the OP seems to be after the consistency of our meta-theory. Thus, there cannot be any mathematical answer, simply because there is nothing to work inside. Rather, there can only be intuitive explanations that try to show that logical axioms are "true" in a "model" (whatever these mean) and our symbol manipulation rules seem to preserve this etc. A contradiction proven from the logical axioms would indicate a fundamental problem in our understanding of language and truth. FOL being inconsistent would be the beginning of downfall of human species!

Comment: Well, maybe induction fails at the $2^{10000000000000000000}$ step. We could never know! :-)

Comment: Oh come on, don't be such an Edward Nelson :-)

Comment: He died recently, if I recall correctly. So I can't quite be like him for a while...

Comment: The proof that FOL (i.e., the predicate calculus with any given collection of function and predicate symbols) is *consistent* is standard: you take the model in which the universe comprises exactly one element. This reduces the consistency of FOL to the consistency of propositional logic. The "sufficiently strong" condition in the incompleteness theorems is important.

Comment: @Rob: Sure. But why is propositional calculus consistent? :-)

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: because it is said to be so in eternal tables of truths handed down to us by the gods :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove contradiction by constructing results which stem from them that contradict.  Right? If A leads to Z and B leads to NOT Z then something is obviously fishy.  Or equally showing that C leads to both Y and NOT Y simultaneously.

The inability to show contradiction does not prove anything.  Indeed even the ability to demonstrate consistency in any given set of logic does not prove that the logic is valid.

Logics are constructed by logicians that are self-consistent but contradict other forms of logics, each based on its own set of axioms.   Thus it is unfair and even irrational to judge one train of thought based in one set of logical principles against that of another. A logic can only be disproved through self-inconsistency, or inconsistency with the real world if you want to go there, but not through inconsistency between "worlds" of logic.

Even if you do show that a premise results in a contradiction. Does that necessarily prove that the premise is false? Ultimately though, and I think you have failed to realize this (many people do), but the Law of Non-Contradiction that prohibits contradiction in logic is ***itself*** an axiom.

Id love to ask a question. What should we do when mathematics or logic contradicts reality?

I want to point out the fact that reality has already contradicted mathematics and logic.  Take Euclidean geometry, for example. It makes the assumption that space is flat (Euclidean).  Most of modern mathematics is based atop of these fundamental assumptions about geometry, including the all-important calculus. All of modern physics, too.  Except one day Einstein comes along and shows that real space is curved. What can we conclude but all of the mathematics we've been using all along is built on flat-space assumptions and is faulty at the fundamental level - at least to the real world we apply it in.  How do you rectify that?  There is the good-old "accurate enough" argument, and of course we have invented other forms of geometry, but... convolution is the key to success.

The law of non-contradiction is pretty steadfast in logic and mathematics. But in quantum physics - the reality from which the entire universe is built - allows a certain degree of contradictory truths. And gad-zooks! The law of non-contradiction might actually be fallible or non-applicable in certain contexts of reasoning.

If you can appreciate any of this from a pure mathematical or pure logical perspective, or the significance it has on physics... just imagine the implications in philosophy, religion, morality.

Answer (score 1):

For a [first order theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), basically a set of "axioms" formulated in a first order language, you have [Gödel's completeness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem). The theorem establishes that a first order theory is consistent(i.e. non-contradictory) is and only if you have a model for that theory(i.e. a "real" mathematical object satisfying the axioms of the theory).

From this you can know that group theory, ring theory, field theory and, in general, every first order theory that has a model is a consistent theory.

To see this you proceed using the completeness theorem and observing, for example, that $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ is a model for group theory, and $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+,.)$ is a model for field and ring theory.

Comment: Usually, Godel's completeness theorem -- as well as the link -- refers to a theorem that says that a theorem is provable (given some deduction schemes) iff it is true in each model. It seems to me that this is not exactly the same as you say. Moreover, as far as I know, nobody ever formally proved the consistency of ZFC or Peano arithmetic (and hence all mathematics)..

Comment: @PeterFranek: Both statements are true and both are usually referred to as Gödel's completeness theorem.

You can prove consistency of PA in ZFC. As for the consistency of ZFC, you cannot prove the consistency of ZFC within ZFC, however you can do this in ZFC+large cardinals.

Comment: @Burak Right, I agree. But to say that finding a model is a "proof" is a bit slippery slope. It might be that Peano arithmetic is inconsistent, I wouldn't be surprised at all. The natural numbers, as we know them, are not something you can touch, analyze, weight and measure and say "Ok, it exists". Therefore, I have problem with this answer.

Comment: The completeness theorem is the left-to-right direction of the statement that a first-order theory is consistent iff it has a model. The right-to-left direction is the soundness theorem for first-order logic and is what you need to go from the existence of a model to the consistency of a theory. As Pipicito's example $(\mathbb{Z}_2, +, .)$ shows, you need very little set-theoretic strength to construct a group, or a field or a ring, in fact, much less strength than you need to specify a first-order logic or state what it means for a theory to be consistent.